# Using ndarray_parallel Zip to iterate through rows of a Array2 and items of Array1

Tags: parallel-processing, rust

I would like to  iterate through rows of an Array2 and items of an Array1 in parallel and do some computation on them with side effects.

I tried something like below,

```
extern crate ndarray;
extern crate ndarray_parallel;

use ndarray::{Array2, Array, Zip, Axis};
use ndarray_parallel::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut a = Array2::<f64>::zeros((5, 5));
    let b = Array::from_iter(0..5);
    let c = vec![1,2,3,4,5];
    let mut d = vec![1,2,3,4,5];

    let z = Zip::from(a.axis_iter(Axis(0))).and(&b);
    z.par_apply(|x,y| {d[*y as usize] =  10});
}
```

But the compiler is complaining.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Multiple misconceptions here. `vec![0..128]` is a vector with one element, which happens to be a range. And `par_apply` takes a `Fn` anyway, you can't mutate a captured variable inside it. But it is not clear what you want, hard to give suggestions.

Comment: ah sorry i have corrected the mistakes. hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple misconceptions in your code, correct me if any of the followings is not what you want:

- `b` seems to serve as index to the vector. You can use `Zip::indexed` to produce index along with element directly, no need for an explicit index array.
- `axis_iter` returns an iterator which traverses all axis of underlying `ndarray`. You probably want `index_axis` to traverse one of them.
- Your arrays host both integers and floats. In `rust` you can't apply arithmetic operations between the two.
- `par_apply` takes a `Fn`, so it can't mutate captured variables.

All things considered, the code probably should look like this:

```rust
use ndarray::{Array2, Zip, Axis};
use ndarray_parallel::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let a = Array2::<f64>::zeros((5, 5));
    let mut d = vec![1.,2.,3.,4.,5.];

    Zip::indexed(a.index_axis(Axis(0), 0))
        .and(&mut d)
        .par_apply(|_i, x, y| *y = x + 10.);
}
```